# How to make matched text bold with jquery chosen?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am wondering how to make the matched part of the autocomplete suggestions bold when using jquery chosen plugin?

Anyone knows how to do that?

http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On their example page this is the css selector they use:

```
.chzn-container .chzn-results li em {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

The matched text is wrapped in an `<em />` so you might need to set `font-style: normal;' as well.

Answer (score 0):

Yes Just in your php page search the result with the passed string and then change it using bold tag.Like

```
$result='Tom Cruise';//retreived frmo database
$passed_string='Tom';//passed string from which db is searched
then
$result=str_replace($passed_string,'<b>'.$passed_string.'</b>',$result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Or this following CSS property as the name has changed

```
.chosen-container .chosen-results li em {
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```